# How to get values from a table row of textboxes into a List of objects , from ContentPlaceholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012, master-pages

I have a table of blank textboxes on a page, if the user puts anything in any of the textboxes I want to save that information in a list of objects. None of these are required, if they enter anything in any row, I want to capture it.
Here is the object:

```
public class Siblings
{
    public string SiblingName { get; set; }
    public string SiblingSchool { get; set; }
    public string SiblingID { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the table:

```
<asp:Content ID="SiblingContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderSibling" runat="server" >
<asp:Panel ID="SiblingInformation" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Inherit" Visible="False" >    
    <table id="SiblingTable" runat="server" > 
        <tr> 
            <td class="header">   
                <asp:Label ID="SiblingNameLabel" runat="server" Text="Sibling Full Name" ></asp:Label> 
            </td> 
            <td class="header">   
                <asp:Label ID="SiblingSchoolLabel" runat="server" Text="Sibling School"></asp:Label> 
            </td>
            <td class="header"> 
                <asp:Label ID="SiblingIDLabel" runat="server" Text="Sibling ID"></asp:Label> 
            </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="SiblingName1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="SiblingSchool1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="SiblingID1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="SiblingName2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="SiblingSchool2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="SiblingID2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="SiblingName3" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="SiblingSchool3" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="SiblingID3" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

And here is what I have so far in my attempt to get the users data into an object list (I had to do this one step at a time to help myself understand what is happening, please consolidate if you like):

```
        ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder;
        Panel siblingPanel;
        Table siblingTable;
        TextBox tbox;
        int i = 1;
        mpContentPlaceHolder =
            (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderSibling") as ContentPlaceHolder;
        if (mpContentPlaceHolder != null)
        {
            siblingPanel =
               (Panel)mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("SiblingInformation") as Panel;
            if (siblingPanel != null)
            {
                siblingTable =
                    (Table)siblingPanel.FindControl("SiblingTable");
                if (siblingTable != null)
                {
                    foreach (TableRow tr in siblingTable.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Cells)
                        {
                            foreach (Control c in tc.Controls)
                            {
                                if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                                {
                                    tbox = (TextBox)c;
                                    if (!(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbox.Text)))
                                    {
                                        AllSiblings[i].SiblingName = tbox.Text;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What I want to have after this is completed is a session for each sibling object, so I can access them later from another ContentPlaceholder. I've tried to give the textboxes ID's that lend themselves to determining is this is a name, school or ID, but I'm not sure how to make use of that.
Thank you--

Comment: @User....I believe your <table> needs to be an <asp:table>. I don't think the code behind will se it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of siblings muuch more easily, simply by doing this:

```
private Siblings GetSiblings(string name, string school, string id)
{
Siblings siblings = new Siblings()
  {
     Name = name,
     School = school,
     Id= id

   }

return siblings;
}


private CreateSiblingsList()
{
   List<Siblings> list = new List<Siblings>();

  // First Sibling, carry on for rest siblings
   list.Add(GetSiblings(sib1name.Text,sibling1school.Text,sib1id.Text)); 
}
```

do similarly for N numbers of siblings and use the list as you want. You can declare the list as global , in case you need in some other part of the code.

Please make this part more clear , what actually you want to say

> What I want to have after this is completed is a session for each
>   sibling object, so I can access them later from another
>   ContentPlaceholder. I've tried to give the textboxes ID's that lend
>   themselves to determining is this is a name, school or ID, but I'm not
>   sure how to make use of that.

Comment: Just had a code review with my elusive mentor who made approximately the same suggestion. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: We created the Siblings object as you suggested, and if the Sibling object is not null it is assigned a Session. Now, from other ContentPlaceholders I can easily determine if any siblings were added.

Comment: @Jazzy ... it would be more appreciable if you accept it as your answer :)